# Does Amazon have anything like EFS, only with redundancy?

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have an application on AWS, that uses a MySQL database and an EFS file store. We've got the database set up with multi-AZ redundancy, but I don't see anything similar for the EFS file store.

Is there a way to get a similar redundancy and failover capability for EFS? Or for something else that an EC2 Linux instance can mount as a file system?

Comment: AWS FSx? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fsx/latest/WindowsGuide/high-availability-multiAZ.html

Comment: @ceejayoz Linux clients need FSx for Lustre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon EFS already supports multi-AZ availability. You need only to choose Regional availability when creating the filesystem. This is the default setting.

[image: EFS create filesystem with Regional availability]

You can see whether the EFS filesystem is regional by checking the Availability Zone column in the filesystem listing in the AWS console.

[image: AWS EFS filesystem listing]

Comment: And I am a complete moron. My boss just sent me the relevant excerpt from the FAQ. Getting the urge to (as George Washington so eloquently put it in a dispatch to the Second Continental Congress) "retire to the backcountry and live in a wigwam."